# power set of non discrete set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory

maybe my question seems easy, but I'm not sure how to answer it.

Let $X=[0,1]$ (you can write in open set too). How to get the power set of $X$? Can we list it?

Second, if  $\tau =$ power set of $X$, could $\tau$ become the topology of $X$?. thanks in advance and I'll appreciate your answers and advice.

Comment: $X$ is already too big to list, and its power set is even bigger.  In general, if $A$ is a set,  the power set of $A$ has cardinality strictly larger than that of $A$.  If $X$ is a set then its power set is the set of all subsets of $X$, so it includes everything and thus satisfies the definition of a  topology.

Comment: $X$ is already uncountable, and hence unlistable. $\operatorname{Pow}(X)$ is bigger and is most definitely uncountable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for every set X we can define for sure two topologies. The $\mathscr{T}=\{\emptyset,X\}$ which is the minimum topology you can define on a space X and $\mathscr{T}=\mathscr{P}(X)$ which is the maximum topology you can define on a space X. So yes, the τ you are talking about can be a topology of X. As fas as the power set of X is concerned, its cardinality is strictly greater than the cardinality of the interval $[0,1]$. The interval $[0,1]$ consists of infinite uncountable points. Think that the power set of $[0,1]$ will include every singleset $\{x\}$ where $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: so, i could say that $([0,1],\tau)$ which is $\tau=\mathcal{P}([0,1])$ can be topological space. am i right?

Comment: Yes, of course. We have the empty set and the whole [0,1] in the τ collection. If we have two subsets of [0,1], the intersection of them also is in the collection τ, and finally, if $U_i\in\tau$,$ i\in I$ where I is an arbitary set of indexes, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\in\tau$. So, τ is a topology for [0,1].

Comment: If so, may I ask for the references? this is for my master's degree trial (hope I could graduate this year) and I haven't got a suitable reference for this material

Comment: You could read about general topology here: http://math.wsu.edu/students/jstreipel/notes/topology2.pdf . I think its very helpful!